# How is PostgreSQL citext stored in a b-tree index? Lower case or as it is?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, case-insensitive, b-tree-index

I am using `citext` in `PostgreSQL` for all text column types. I wonder about `citext` performance.

I performed simple `WHERE` statement benchmarks over text columns that have a b-tree index, but I couldn't see any differences in terms of query cost.

For example:

```
Select * From table_text where a = '1';

Select * From table_citext where a= '1';
```

These queries have identical query costs.

As far as I understand, `citext` stores the string as it is without converting it to lower case. So when a value is used in the `WHERE` clause, it uses the `lower` function for every comparison in each node of the b-tree index (I used a b-tree index).

If this is as I say, this should have caused performance problems, but it hasn't.

How does PostgreSQL achieve this?
How does PostgreSQL store `citext` column values in a b-tree index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`citext` is stored as it is input, without any conversion to lower case. This also holds for storage as b-tree index keys.

The magic happens in the comparison function for `citext`:

```c
/*
 * citextcmp()
 * Internal comparison function for citext strings.
 * Returns int32 negative, zero, or positive.
 */
static int32
citextcmp(text *left, text *right, Oid collid)
{
    char       *lcstr,
               *rcstr;
    int32       result;

    /*
     * We must do our str_tolower calls with DEFAULT_COLLATION_OID, not the
     * input collation as you might expect.  This is so that the behavior of
     * citext's equality and hashing functions is not collation-dependent.  We
     * should change this once the core infrastructure is able to cope with
     * collation-dependent equality and hashing functions.
     */

    lcstr = str_tolower(VARDATA_ANY(left), VARSIZE_ANY_EXHDR(left), DEFAULT_COLLATION_OID);
    rcstr = str_tolower(VARDATA_ANY(right), VARSIZE_ANY_EXHDR(right), DEFAULT_COLLATION_OID);

    result = varstr_cmp(lcstr, strlen(lcstr),
                        rcstr, strlen(rcstr),
                        collid);

    pfree(lcstr);
    pfree(rcstr);

    return result;
}
```

So yes, this should incur some overhead. How expensive it is will also depend on the default collation of the database.

I'll demonstrate this using a query without an index. I am using the German collation:

```
SHOW lc_collate;
 lc_collate 
------------
 de_DE.utf8
(1 row)
```

First using `text`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE large_text(t text NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO large_text
   SELECT i||'text'
   FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS i;

VACUUM (FREEZE, ANALYZE) large_text;

\timing on

SELECT * FROM large_text WHERE t = TEXT 'mama';
 t 
---
(0 rows)

Time: 79.862 ms
```

Now the same experiment with `citext`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE large_citext(t citext NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO large_citext
   SELECT i||'text'
   FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS i;

VACUUM (FREEZE, ANALYZE) large_citext;

\timing on

SELECT * FROM large_citext WHERE t = CITEXT 'mama';
 t 
---
(0 rows)

Time: 567.739 ms
```

So `citext` is about seven times slower.

But don't forget that each of these experiments performed a sequential scan with a million comparisons.
**If you use an index, the difference will not be noticeable:**

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON large_text (t);

Time: 5443.993 ms (00:05.444)

SELECT * FROM large_text WHERE t = CITEXT 'mama';
 t 
---
(0 rows)

Time: 1.867 ms


CREATE INDEX ON large_citext (t);

Time: 28009.904 ms (00:28.010)

SELECT * FROM large_citext WHERE t = CITEXT 'mama';
 t 
---
(0 rows)

Time: 1.988 ms
```

You see that `CREATE INDEX` takes much longer for the `citext` columns (it has to perform a lot of comparisons), but the queries take about the same time.

The reason is that you need only few comparisons if you use an index scan: for each of the 2-3 index blocks you access you perform a binary search, and you may have to re-check the table row found in the case of a bitmap index scan.